# Is there a way I can reformat numbers in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, formatting

I would like, under Microsoft Word 2019, to replace an italicized counting number followed by a space with the same number in superscript.

So, for instance, `<em>27</em>`  would be replaced by `<sup>27</sup>`.

I can see one way to do this but it circumvents Word and is not a particularly good solution: save as HTML, edit the HTML to make such substitutions, and reimport it from Word.

Are there other, more direct macro-like ways that would allow such a global search-and-replace?

Comment: Word does allow search-and-replace of format, not just text. Click on `More>>` in the Search/Replace dialog, and then `Format ▼`

Comment: Thanks; will explore.

Comment: It depends on how the original number is produced. What you are showing is a hard-coded number in the emphasis style. Normally numbering in Word is done using list numbering or SEQ fields rather than manually typing numbers.

Comment: The numbers are gradually added.

Comment: Sorry; I meant they are manually added.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I've found the Format link, but I'm not sure how to use it; my trial runs have failed. How can I select to match an italicized (and manually specified, not calculated) number and space to a superscript number?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin (I mean, after clicking on Format).

Comment: I don't remember the details of whatever Word uses instead of regular expressions, but... If you wanted to replace every occurrence of foo bolded with foo italicized, you'd enter "foo" in the search field, then format/character/bold, then enter "foo" in the replace field, then format/character/italic. Then, when you click on the do-it button, it'll replace all the bolded foos - and only the bolded foos - with italic foos.

Comment: I tried a few permutations in a test document and have not yet gotten a bold or italic original text to change to anything else.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I selected strong emphasis and bold for text that, in Word's opinion, was only bold. Since then I got what I wanted by selecting `Font` to specify bold or italic as they exist in the document, and `Style` under `Format ▼` to get footnote heading-style text. @JeffZeitlin, would you restate your comments (and maybe this comment) as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to reformat only numbers that are in Italics or only numbers that are in the Emphasis style. If they are in the Emphasis style in Word, you could simply redefine that style to be superscript instead of Italics. If manually formatted, is there anything else in the document that is in Italics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word allows you to search and replace formats, not just text. To do this, you click on the `More>>` button, which expands the box to add some additional search/replace parameters, and then click on the `Format ▼` button to apply the attributes you are interested in. For example, if I wanted to replace bold foo with italic foo, I would enter **foo** in the ‘Find what’ field, then `Format ▼`/`Font` and select the font style ‘bold’, then enter **foo** again in ‘Replace with’ and then `Format ▼`/`Font` and select the font style ‘italic’. When you click on `Replace` or `Replace All`, it will find only bolded foo, and replace it with italicised foo. You can also apply styles, paragraph formats, etc., in any combination, and distinguish between Latin and non-Latin text; you can even search and replace format without specifying text (it will apply to all text - that is, if you don’t fill in text in ‘Find what’ and set the format to bold, and leave ‘Replace with’ empty and set the format to italic, it will replace all bold in the document with italic).